# Is the logo on the back of the iPhone 5S a mirror like on the iPhone 4S?

Tags: iphone

I have my iPhone 4S, and the logo on the back is like a mirror. (I like it because if I get an eyelash stuck in my eye, I can use it to look into my eye up close and get it out.) Is the logo on the back of the (silver) iPhone 5S a mirror as well?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WCmSwYWWDs8) : Yes it's the case on all 3 models.

With the iPhone 5, it's was only the case with the white model.

Answer (score 0):

Another tip to add. Slightly less convenient tho. You can always open the camera from the lockscreen, and use the front facing camera as a mirror.

Comment: I have to agree it's a possibility. But I find it really lacks of sharpness.